# Can anyone help translate an artist's seal for me? (Characters identified: 臨摹)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, transcription

I have an original art print of a Wei Jin tombs brick but I can't get an accurate translation of the artist's seal. Below is a picture of the seal. Thank you to all who reply. [image]

Answer (score 1):

临摹 means "Imitation" or "Copy". It is a practice where aspiring artists learn by copying masterpieces.

In exploring seal script fonts (篆体), it is evident that the structure of the lower character originates from the large seal script (大篆). The composition of the upper character is more elusive within seal scripts. It appears to most closely resemble traditional Chinese, a composition prevalently used in Chinese speakers:

[image: Decomposing the seal]

Comment: Hello. I was wondering if there are any numbers in the seal or anything which would indicate what type of copy this is. It might be along the lines of "Artist's Copy" or "Copy #25" or "Proof Copy", etc. Thank you.

Comment: @IvanHolubetz Hello. I didn't identify information relevant to your description. Meanwhile, as far as I know, it is not  common practice to put this information along with "Copy". A possibility is that you can find the artist's name in a separate seal on the art piece.